# Int cannot be dereferenced. How do I fix this?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in programming. I know why I am getting this error at int result merge(list1)..., but I don't know how to fix this error. I did look at some of the questions related to this error here, but I am still confused. I do not want anyone to write a code for me, but I would appreciate some explanation. Thank you.

```
public int merge(int list1){
   try{
  int count = 0;
  for(int i= 0; i < 2; i++){
    count++;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the name of the file to be opened for " + count + " list: ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.print("The list " + count + " is: " );

    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
      if(!inputFile.hasNextInt()){
        String ss = inputFile.next();
      }else{
        int length = 1;
        list1 = inputFile.nextInt();
        System.out.print(list1 + " ");

        } 

      } 

     System.out.println();  
  }

  int result = merge(list1).insertEnd(list1);


} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("could not find the file");
}
  return result;  
}
```

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: `merge()` returns an `int` and you're expecting it (`int`) to have an `insertEnd()` function, which I'm guessing it hasn't.

Comment: @Biffen Java language

Comment: Then `int` most certainly doesn't have an `insertEnd()` method. What is `merge(list1).insertEnd(list1)` supposed to do anyway?

Answer (score 2):

In the expression `merge(list1).insertEnd(list1);`, `merge(list1)` has type `int` because that's the return type of the `merge` method.

On this expression of type `int`, you're trying to call the `insertEnd` method, which cannot work because `int` is a primitive type and has no such method.

Your error message "cannot be dereferenced" explains that `int` is not a *reference* type (it is an int, which is a *primitive* type), so it cannot be "de-referenced" (meaning, you cannot follow its pointer to find an instance in memory on which you could call the `insertEnd` method)